# Protocol with associated type. How to avoid to manually assign a type on all the implementations of the protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, redux

I am doing my own Redux/Flux easy implementation and I am trying to model some data structures.

Basically I have a state protocol that can have an associated type action.

```
protocol State {
    associatedtype ActionType: StateAction
}
```

Then I define my states like:

```
struct BoxState: State {
    typealias ActionType = Action
    var boxes:[Box]
}

extension BoxState {
    enum Action: StateAction {
        case select(String)
        case reshape(String, CGRect)
        case delete(String)
        case add(CGPoint)
    }
}
```

What I dont like from this is that I will have to define the `associatedtype` for each implementation of the protocol, even when every enum will have the same type.

1 - Is there a way to force each State implementation to have an enum type `Action`?. I understand that `Action` is actually of type `BoxState.Action`, but maybe there is a way to abstract it even better.

Edit: Big explanation, not needed for the question above, but might serve as explanation: 
I started doing an easy Redux implementation, because I like the reducer functions and the views reacting to a state.

As suggested here, as suggested here, a store should dispatch actions. 
This is my very rough implementation so far:

```
protocol StateAction {}

protocol State {
    associatedtype ActionType: StateAction
}

protocol Dispatcher {
    associatedtype Action: StateAction
    func dispatch(_ action: Action)
}

class StateStore<Type: State>: Dispatcher {

    typealias Action = Type.ActionType

    private var subscribers:[(Type)->()] = []
    var onDispatch:((Action)->())?

    var state: Type! {
        didSet {
            self.didUpdateState(state)
        }
    }

    func didUpdateState(_ state: Type) {
        self.subscribers.forEach { $0(state) }
    }

    func addSubscriber(_ subscriber: @escaping (Type)->())  {
        self.subscribers.append(subscriber)
    }

    func dispatch(_ action: Action) {
        self.onDispatch?(action)
    }
}
```

What I think is wrong is that the `State` is defining `Action`s. The views are the ones triggering actions, and those actions should be handled to mutate one or more states. Still the "technical" problem explained in the beginning might have a solution.

Comment: Show for what you're using this *associatedtype* `ActionType`

Comment: I have updated the question with a broader explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need a default type. Then the type will be the same for all of the implemented structures/classes.

```
protocol State {
    associatedtype ActionType: StateAction = BoxState.Action
}
```